# Feature extraction from multiple curves

Tags: machine-learning, svm, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I got multiple curves from different sensor but all attached in the same moving object.

Now I want to extract features from it , let's say I have cut 0-10 as window1 , so in window1 I got 5 graphs ,each graph represents one sensor in a particular position, each sensor generates 3 curves , x(red) ,y(green),and z(blue), as shown below:

[image: Entire graph is a single window] **Entire graph is a single window

Since all sensors are attached in a same moving object ,I thought these graphs and curves should have some relations I could use as features to use in machine learning algorithms(especially SVM) . But they are too many, I am kind of lost.

How many reasonable features I could generate from this single window?

I am so appreciated for any advices .. Thanks!

Comment: What is "cut 0-10", does this refer to time? Are these velocity curves or positions? What is your overall task with this data?

Comment: Yes , 0-10 is in seconds , and they are accelerometer readings , the overall task is detecting movement pattens . At same time , I got entire Euler angle  data as well ..

Comment: So basically, all of these readings describe the same movement, just in different coordinate systems? Sounds like a job for the orthogonal Procrustes problem.

Comment: yes exactly !They are in same objects but in different coordinate system,I have calculate as many features as I can for individual curve include fft of each of them ,but I think they must have some connection between different coordinate system,because my math is poor ,I only calculate each coordinate system's x*y*z which is the convolution result of them ,I am not sure it helps ,and maybe I could use this result calculate correlation coefficient between different coordinate system

Comment: Do you want to upload some of this data somewhere, I think I know how to match them up but it's hard to know without trying...

Comment: Thanks cfh! the original data is kind of complex https://www.dropbox.com/s/h4as5f1yz8kn0up/20150518_113844.json?dl=0 just ignore everything except 'datapkg'

Comment: Well, yes, that's a bit too complex for me to parse... I was hoping for just the numbers you used to generate those 5 plots in plain ASCII format.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xtwhiet3r52jgrz/example?dl=0 here is the plan text one

Comment: I am very interested in the orthogonal procrustes problem as you indicated , I'm currently just using convolution equation to fuse three axis up in a single coordinate system and then find the correlation coefficient between other coordinate system's convolution data, not sure if it got some real meaning but just trying ..

Comment: I can read that file. Are the 'euler_x' or the 'areal_x' fields the good ones?

Comment: yes, euler_x means the euler x axis reading from euler sensor ,areal_x means the x axis accelerometer reading from the sensor . In the graph ,i only past 5 accelerometer reading from 5 sensors , each picture contain areal_x ,areal_y,and areal_z , there is another half I didn't uploaded is the euler_x,euler_y,and euler_z from 5 sensors , as same as accelerometer I use 5 figs to show them.

Comment: There must be something wrong with the data, I plotted the areal_* curves but they look very different from the plots you showed. Even the scales are very different across the five plots.

Comment: http://imgur.com/OPegPAK

Comment: thank cfh , the data is correct because I picked a random one window to you ( sorry I got too many samples and unable to find the original one , they are just been measured in different condition) , and window size might differ since I've altered it,but I've looked the picture the data is correct I am sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform the different time series to live in the same coordinate system by solving the [orthogonal Procrustes problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem).

Here are the five arrays of Euler angles that you gave me (they are stored in `arr[0]` through `arr[4]` as 169x3 numpy arrays):

[image: plots before]

Now we solve the orthogonal Procrustes problem by the following Python routine, which allows us to rotate one of the arrays to match another one as closely as possible:

```
def rotate_into(arr0, arr1):
    """Solve orthogonal Procrustes problem"""
    M = dot(arr0.T, arr1)
    (U,S,V) = svd(M)
    Q = dot(U, V)  # the rotation matrix which transforms arr0 into arr1
    return arr0.dot(Q)
```

`svd` is the singular value decomposition and lives in `numpy.linalg.svd`. Now we can apply this routine to each array and transform it to be as close as possible to the reference array, here the first one:

```
reference = 0

for i in range(0,5):
    subplot(2,3, i+1)
    plot(rotate_into(arr[i], arr[reference]))
```

[image: plots after]

Now all the series are comparable, and you can easily compute features from them by taking the mean, the standard deviation, and so on.

Comment: cfh , you are genius and thank you very much for deep digging into my question. I believe you are right but still several points I don't understand : first , is the orthogonal Procrustes kind of changing original physical properties ? Because the result been transformed seems all altered . second , why does it suitable for the system contain multi coordinate systems? Third : because I compare this window to another ,should I calculate entire mean or standard deviation by adding up every curve I have ?

Comment: @Yank: In your device, all the sensors have different physical orientation. Solving the Procrustes problem attempts to find for each sensor a rotation matrix `Q` such that, when the sensor data is rotated by it, it is as close as possible to the reference data, which in my example was simply the first sensor. The effect is similar as if all the motion sensors in your device had been installed with the same orientation in the first place.

Comment: @Yank: I should mention that if you want to compare different windows, it may be best to compute for each sensor the proper rotation matrix `Q` once beforehand and not change it per window. If you wish you can now simply average all 5 sensors together to get features, or you could keep the sensors separate if this is important for your data.

Comment: this method blows me away . I never thought this question will lead me to solve another big issue in my system design before I see your answer . here is my understanding of this transform: since all sensor originally calibrated in the same condition (calibrate on the same flat desk and orientation) then I attach them into my object's different position ,some is vertical some is horizontal, thus they are hard to get reasonable overall system feature.After I transformed by using your method,I select a reference point ,and every sensor can be considered they are in same coordinate system.r?

Comment: I'm guessing orientation is a significant significant feature, certainly the different orientations between the sensors. Wouldn't this completely undo that?

Comment: @Yank: Yes, that's exactly right. As far as possible, this method rotates the sensors to have more or less the same coordinate system (using least squares fit).

Comment: @Gerard: I assume that the device is rigid and therefore the relative orientation of the sensors to each other doesn't change during operation, so there would be no usable information in the orientation anyway. If there is, you can actually treat the computed rotation matrix `Q` as a feature, and it will tell you exactly how the relative orientation of the sensors to each other is changing.

Comment: @cfh so physically , the angle change are not altered , just from it's world coordinate system to reference coordinate system , if I transform it back to world coordinate system and nothing will change right ?

Comment: @Yank: Yes, you can use the computed matrix `Q` to rotate back and forth between the sensor's local coordinate system and the reference coordinate system. No information is lost.

Comment: Is this method also suitable for the range of acceleration , or rotation angle increment?

Comment: @cfh I wish I could give you 10000 up votes but stack overflow doesn't allow me to do that ..  glad to meet you and your elegant answer :)

Comment: @cfh Ah, I didn't get that in the original post, I assumed they were part of a body suit, of sorts.